Installing tensorflow on a fresh Ubuntu 22.04 linking to GPU
I have been trying all day to install tensorflow with GPU support on a fresh machine with Ubuntu 22.04, but I am struggling heavily to say the least.
The install is completely fresh and I have an Nvidia RTX 6000 available on the machine, however I can not for the life of me get tensorflow to accept it.
I run the following (from a fresh build):
#General system updates
sudo apt update
apt install python3-pip

#Install the nvidia driver
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-550 nvidia-dkms-550

#Install CUDA
apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit


#Install Bazelisk
wget https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk/releases/download/v1.8.1/bazelisk-linux-amd64
chmod +x bazelisk-linux-amd64
sudo mv bazelisk-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/bazel

#Install tensorflow
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
cd tensorflow
./configure

However this runs into the below error
Inconsistent CUDA toolkit path: /usr vs /usr/lib
Asking for detailed CUDA configuration...

which I simply cant fix - I have tried rebuilding the machine like 5 times and everything else under the sun, but I cant for the life of me get it to work.
Any and all help is exceptionally appreciated.

For everyone having the same problem as me - it can be fixed extremely easily. Instead of building from source simply use pip (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) BUT download a previous version, specifically
pip install tensorflow[and-cuda]==2.15.1
With the above it works flawlessly with pip without having to build from source
